# Using Loops to Generate Dynamic Channel Field Names?

Tags: expressionengine

Having a bit of an issue generating channel fields based on a variable. Below is my attempt at a PHP solution:

```
{related_entries id="image_gallery"}
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) { ?>
        {image_<?php echo $i; ?>}
    <?php } ?>
{/related_entries}
```

Unfortunately ExpresssionEngine doesn't render these tags and just outputs them as: 
{image_1} {image_2} {image_3}... etc.

I've tried some other looping plugins with no luck either, but I assume there is a plugin or method out there to help me.

**Bonus question:** Ideally, I will need a method that I can also check to see if the channel field actually has any data like: {if image_x}{image_x}{/if}

Comment: FYI: we all moved to the EE specific beta site (http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com). The site is currently in private beta. Do you need an invite?

Comment: Just to clarify - you have 15 fields in your the channel which is displaying entries in your **image_gallery** field, and they are named `{image_1}`, `{image_2}`, etc?

Comment: @MediaGirl - Sounds great, would love one!

Comment: @DerekHogue - That is correct.

Comment: Is PHP set to Input? I can't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: To which email address should I send the beta invite?

Comment: Thanks @DerekHogue - I'm glad it was such a simple mistake. PHP Parsing Stage: "Input" (instead of "Output") needed to be set. I guess I'm not allowed to answer my own question yet, but I will make the edits when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have set PHP to parse on input in your template preferences. That should do the trick.